# How to access relational data in DynamoDB (Keys vs Queries)

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

What is the best way to access relational data in DynamoDB? Is it best to store information redundantly and update it as needed, or to query every time you need access to relational data?

For example say I have a Team table that has a Members field that stores an array of member ids that also include the member's name.

**Team**

```
Members: [
  {member1: "John"},
  {member2: "Sam"},
  {member3: "Pam"}
]
```

Whenever my application needs access to a team's members, all I have to do is call `get` on the teams members field. Then if I need additional team member data I can further call get on the entire member record.

One of the concerns I have with this method is having to update the names inside of the members array each time a person updates their name. Not to mention all of the other places the user's name could also be stored.

My main question then is whether I should be instead querying for these records every time instead of storing this data inside of the team record.

For example should I instead `query all members who have team 123`?

Would querying be more expensive to continually do, or would having to update all of this dependent data be more expensive?

I know that the query route is less of a headache then trying to prevent data anomalies, but querying may also require multiple calls to get the same data.

Answer (score 0):

dynamodb write operations are more expensive than read ops, and become more when you add some secondary indexes to the table (or partition)

Also, synchronizing values in different items may charge additional fees if the sync operation must be done in a transaction to ensure atomicity

It meanly depends on your application needs and your budget i.e identify how many requests per use case you will approximatively have during a period (ex: month) then try to optimize the cost of use cases that generate the most of your traffic, regardless of their type (read or write).

For some read use cases, you may accept the eventual consistency of the read model and use a cache (e.g S3 files) it still an option...